# Checkbox to change button actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to make in a small program I'm creating that when one checkbox is selected the action performed for a specific button to be changed to another action performed, let's say the button action performed gives the result of 1+2, I want when I check the checkbox to make the button action performed be 1-3 just for example.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;

public class frame extends JFrame { // Declaring the frame class

public frame() { // crating a constructor 
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2)); // Creating 5 lines and 2 rows
    // first label for adding the first number
    JLabel label = new JLabel("First Number");
    getContentPane().add(label);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    // first text field
    final JTextField text = new JTextField(8);
    getContentPane().add(text);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    // second label for adding second number
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Second Number");
    getContentPane().add(label1);
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    // second text field
    final JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
    getContentPane().add(text1);
    text1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    // third label for the result
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Result is");
    getContentPane().add(label2);
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    // third text field to show the result
    final JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
    getContentPane().add(text2);
    text2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    text2.setEditable(false);
    // Calculation button
    JButton btn = new JButton("Calculate");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String number1, number2, result, ans;
            try {
                /*number1 = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
                number2 = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText());
                result = number1*number2;
                text2.setText(Double.toString(result));*/
                if (text.getText().isEmpty() || text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                number1 = text.getText();
                number2 = text1.getText();
                result = number1.concat(number2);
                text2.toString();
                text2.setText(result);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please add a letter");
            }
        }
    });     
    getContentPane().add(btn);
    // Clear button
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    getContentPane().add(clear);

    final JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("New check box");
    getContentPane().add(chckbxNewCheckBox);

    final JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("New check box");
    getContentPane().add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);

    chckbxNewCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                chckbxNewCheckBox_1.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });

    chckbxNewCheckBox_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (chckbxNewCheckBox_1.isSelected()) {
                chckbxNewCheckBox.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });

    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                text.setText("");
                text1.setText("");
                text2.setText("");
            } catch(Exception e1) {
            }
        }
    });

    //setVisible(true);
    //setSize(400,200);
    //setResizable(false);
    //setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //setTitle("Calculator");
}

public static void main (String args[]) { // Creating the main method
    frame frame = new frame(); // creating an object of the ShowGridLayout class, object is frame.
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in multiple ways.

1. You can have a integer field (member variable or static) and update it's value on selection of different check boxes. Define different method for each kind of action you want to perform and call them in button action listener by looking at the value of the static integer.

OR

2. Keep a reference to the ActionListener added to the button and on selection of the checkbox remove existing action listener from button and add the new one and update the reference to new listener.

I hope it helps.

EDIT 1 : it's better to use radio buttons if you just want to have one selection at a time.

Edit 2: 
Here it is how you can do it using radio buttons and by removing and adding listener.

```
    public class frame extends JFrame { // Declaring the frame class
        final JTextField text;
        final JTextField text1;
        final JTextField text2;

        public frame() { // crating a constructor
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2)); // Creating 5 lines and 2 rows
            // first label for adding the first number
            JLabel label = new JLabel("First Number");
            getContentPane().add(label);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // first text field
            text = new JTextField(8);
            getContentPane().add(text);
            text.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // second label for adding second number
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Second Number");
            getContentPane().add(label1);
            label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // second text field
            text1 = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(text1);
            text1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // third label for the result
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Result is");
            getContentPane().add(label2);
            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // third text field to show the result
            text2 = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(text2);
            text2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            text2.setEditable(false);

            final AddValuesActionListener actionListener = new AddValuesActionListener();
            // Calculation button
            final JButton btn = new JButton("Calculate");
            btn.addActionListener(actionListener);

            final JRadioButton addRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Add", true);
            addRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    btn.removeActionListener(actionListener);
                    btn.addActionListener(new AddValuesActionListener());
                }
            });

            final JRadioButton subtractRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Subtract", true);
            subtractRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    btn.removeActionListener(actionListener);
                    btn.addActionListener(new SubtractValuesActionListener());
                }
            });


            getContentPane().add(btn);
            // Clear button
            JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
            getContentPane().add(clear);

            ButtonGroup radioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
            radioButtons.add(addRadioButton);
            radioButtons.add(subtractRadioButton);
            getContentPane().add(addRadioButton);
            getContentPane().add(subtractRadioButton);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) { // Creating the main method
            frame frame = new frame(); // creating an object of the ShowGridLayout class, object is frame.
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(400, 200);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setTitle("Calculator");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            ;
        }

        private class AddValuesActionListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                text2.setText(text.getText() + "+" + text1.getText());  //Create add values method
            }
        }

        private class SubtractValuesActionListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                text2.setText(text.getText() + "-" + text1.getText());  //Create add values method
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is how you could simply do by checking radio button selection as suggested by @JeriesHG

```
    public class frame extends JFrame { // Declaring the frame class
        final JTextField text;
        final JTextField text1;
        final JTextField text2;

        public frame() { // crating a constructor
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2)); // Creating 5 lines and 2 rows
            // first label for adding the first number
            JLabel label = new JLabel("First Number");
            getContentPane().add(label);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // first text field
            text = new JTextField(8);
            getContentPane().add(text);
            text.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // second label for adding second number
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Second Number");
            getContentPane().add(label1);
            label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // second text field
            text1 = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(text1);
            text1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // third label for the result
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Result is");
            getContentPane().add(label2);
            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            // third text field to show the result
            text2 = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(text2);
            text2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            text2.setEditable(false);

            final JRadioButton addRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Add", true);
            final JRadioButton subtractRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Subtract", true);

            // Calculation button
            final JButton btn = new JButton("Calculate");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  if (addRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                      text2.setText(text.getText() + "+" + text1.getText());  //Create add values method
                  }     else if (subtractRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                      text2.setText(text.getText() + "-" + text1.getText());  //Create subtract values method
                  }
                }
            });

            getContentPane().add(btn);
            // Clear button
            JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
            getContentPane().add(clear);

            ButtonGroup radioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
            radioButtons.add(addRadioButton);
            radioButtons.add(subtractRadioButton);
            getContentPane().add(addRadioButton);
            getContentPane().add(subtractRadioButton);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) { // Creating the main method
            frame frame = new frame(); // creating an object of the ShowGridLayout class, object is frame.
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(400, 200);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setTitle("Calculator");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Parkash Jat
Can you please give me an example for the second option, I don't get it without seeing an example :)

Comment: I have edited my response, with sample code for both my and @JeriesHG 's suggestion

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaank you so much, I will check them, thank you again @user3190129

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand completely, the action of a button depends in a checkbox? If this is correct, then you could have a boolean for the checkbox value or just check the "isSelected" function and in the action performed method, I would just do a boolean check and execute the method I need.

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Calculate");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 if(chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()){
  //do something here
 }else{
  //do this
 }
}
```

EDIT: 
I would also have the "action performed" of a button in a separated method, in order to re-use the code. (in the case I require to use this same method in another button or something like this).

Comment: Your idea is awesome, but the chckbxNewCheckBox when it is used as you mentioned above it is not recognized, because it comes after the btn and was not declared before it, any suggestion for this?

Comment: It seems @user3190129 answered the question, sorry it took a little bit to answer back. Hope it works!